# Does the Midnight Commander have an option to display actual dir sizes?

Tags: files

i have plenty of empty directories and i wonder if there's a way to display actual direcory sizes (after some sort of scan maybe) in MC

Comment: Others already answered Ctrl-Space, but since you mention empty dirs, you may also find this non-MC tip useful: `find . -type d -empty`. Or even `find . -depth -type d -empty -delete` (but be careful: some empty dirs are important).

Comment: Of cours you can also Ctrl+o and then `du -sh */` or `ncdu -rx .`

Answer (score 61):

Press <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd> on current directory and this will show it size. Also, you can use visual select to apply this command on multiply items.

If you press <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd> on `..` directory mc will calculate size of all subdirectories in current dir

To see total size of all directories, you can select them all using <kbd>Inserl</kbd> key, and see total size at the bottom of the panel

Comment: That is right!!

Comment: How to get total size of all selected directories?

Comment: @Maxim you could do that pressing the shortcut on top `..`, then mc would calculate space for all folders in current dir

Comment: Hmm.. I have pressed Ctrl + Space and got size for each directory but not total size. The single way I know for now - choose all files folders and press Ctrl + Space.

Answer (score 16):

Just go to "Command" menu and select "Show directory sizes" in desired root directory.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`gt5`](http://gt5.sourceforge.net) for that.

Comment: How would it be used?